# SetThreadPriority isn't working even though GetThreadPriority indicates that it is

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

I'm calling SetThreadPriority(m_hThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL) and calling GetThreadPriority(m_hThread) immediately after to verify that the priority has been set.  According to GetThreadPriority(), SetThreadPriority() works fine, but the thread's performance doesn't change.

I've created a thread to animate through the frames of an animated GIF.  The GIF animates perfectly as long as there's nothing much else going on, but as soon as the process's main thread gets busy, the GIF freezes until the main thread finishes its work.

I've tried raising the thread to THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST and to THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL but nothing makes any difference.  The GIF thread still freezes when the main thread gets busy.

I've read all I can find online about threading priorities and can find nothing wrong with my code so I'm out of ideas.

Any help is appreciated.

```
m_hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ThreadWrapper, this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);
DWORD dwThreadPriority1 = ::GetThreadPriority(m_hThread);
BOOL b = ::SetThreadPriority(m_hThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);
DWORD dwThreadPriority2 = ::GetThreadPriority(m_hThread);
ASSERT(THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL == dwThreadPriority2);
ResumeThread(m_hThread);
```

Comment: That sounds more like you have a locking problem, that the "main" thread locks some resource for more than it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, all UI should be done from the same thread. In particular, this should be the thread which created the main window

Violating this rule can have unexpected consequences.

Comment: Similarly, any non-trivial work should be moved _out_ of the UI thread whenever possible.